# Only allow private access to website through VPN

Tags: .htaccess, openvpn

I know this may be very basic, but I have a website on my server that I would only like to be accessed by VPN.  I have OpenVPN running on my Windows machine and it is connecting to my server with the VPN.  When the VPN connects I can use the VPN's IP address to hit the site on my server. I would like to block all other methods such as the actual site IP or my domain name.  Would I use htaccess?  What is normally done for private access only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that your server vpn ip is 10.1.2.3 then you should add to your apache configuration

```
Listen 10.1.2.3:80
```

so that you will bind Apache - i.e. will accept incoming requests - only to that address.

Also:

> The Listen directive does not implement Virtual Hosts - it only tells
>   the main server what addresses and ports to listen on. If no
>    directives are used, the server will behave in the same
>   way for all accepted requests. However,  can be used to
>   specify a different behavior for one or more of the addresses or
>   ports. To implement a VirtualHost, the server must first be told to
>   listen to the address and port to be used. Then a 
>   section should be created for the specified address and port to set
>   the behavior of this virtual host. Note that if the  is
>   set for an address and port that the server is not listening to, it
>   cannot be accessed.

i.e. you could leave the original listen directive (listen to all interfaces) and filter the access per virtual host having your "private" virtual host configured like that:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
```

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Finally if for some reason you are restricted to .htaccess only, then you could do in .htaccess:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.1.2.1/24
```

i.e. allowing access only from your vpn subnet.

Take care that you will need to restart the web server after every change.

Comment: Thankyou.  I tried the virtual host method and for some reason it was not excluding even after restarting the server. I used the .htaccess method and that worked.  Is there any risk with this.  Is it less secure?

Comment: @CraigTucker It should be fine, however .htaccess are to be avoided due to performance downgrade and because you don't have a centralized management of them and you could in some cases turn them off accidentaly (for the last one see http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/htaccess-security/)